# Manipulate Json array on select change

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I am new to JQuery and I am wondering if his is possible.
I have a PHP controller that sends a json encoded array to a view,
this is the json array:

```
{"id":"1","color":"blue","description":"This is the color blue"},
{"id":"8","color":"green","description":"This is the color green"},
{"id":"14","color":"red","description":"This is the color red"}
```

Now on the view I have a the following:

```
<select id="selector">
<option value="">Select one</option>
<option value="1">blue</option>
<option value="8">green</option>
<option value="14">red</option>
</select>

<div id="description">

</div>
```

What I want to do is first populate the select list from the json array, then if I select green from the dropdown list the description for green should appear on the div, if I change my selection the appropriate description should appear on the div.
And the option I select should no longer appear on the select list like if I choose green, only red and blue should appear on the available option, if the I select another color let say blue then red and green should be available for another select.

I am currently doing it running a new query onchange of the select but I want to do it without another query and page refresh, I imagine it is possible since I already send the JSON array to the browser.

Hope I am clear on my problem and thank you for your help!

Comment: That's not valid JSON.

Comment: You're going to have to post your Javascript/jQuery code too. I'm guessing the malformed JSON is coming from AJAX, but we need to see how you've got to this point and then we can help you better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var data = [{"id":"1","color":"blue","description":"This is the color blue"},
{"id":"8","color":"green","description":"This is the color green"},
{"id":"14","color":"red","description":"This is the color red"}];
var selector = $('#selector');

data.forEach(function(obj){
   // create option
   var option = $('<option>');
   // set its value
   option.val(obj.id);
   // set its text
   option.text(obj.text);
   // append it to select element
   selector.append(option);
}    
selector.change(function(){
    var value = this.value;
    // show all options
    selector.find('option').show();
    // hide the selected
    $(value).hide();
    // find the selected object
    var selected = data.filter(function(obj){
       return obj.id == value;
    });
    // if returns exactly one show its description
    if (selected.length == 1)
        $('#description').text(selected[0].description);
});
```

Comment: Thank's Almis, this is almost all i need , now just one more thing, how do i remove the selected option, like if i select green, only blue and red should appear but if then i select blue, green should appear again and also red

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you `Json`must be like this :

```
[{"id":"1","color":"blue","description":"This is the color blue"},
{"id":"8","color":"green","description":"This is the color green"},
{"id":"14","color":"red","description":"This is the color red"}]
```

this is some code i have tried i think it will be help you :

```
$(document).ready(function(e){
     $("#selector").on('change',function(){ 
      var dataL= $("#selector option:selected").val();
      $.post("Page_json.php",{myVal:dataL},function(data,message,xhr){
                            if(message==='success'){
                                $.each(data, function(k,v){
                                    if(v.id == dataL){
                                        $("#description").text(v.description);
                                        return false;
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        },'json');


    });
});
```